# Unity SimpleJSON array lags

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, simplejson

Sorry for my English :)

In my project i use SimpleJSON.
I have this json string
This is a planet lists in my game.
I need parsing this json.
But i have 1 problem.
My Unity Editor is freeze!!! When i use cycle.

```
{
 "system_list":
  [
   {
    "system_id":"9", 
    "galaxy":"1",
    "x":"3",
    "y":"2",
    "system_name":"bla bla"
   },
   {
    "system_id":"10"
    "galaxy":"1",
    "x":"1",
    "y":"4",
    "system_name":"NoIQ"}
  ]
}
```

Parsing code this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SimpleJSON;

public class GetJsonList : MonoBehaviour
{
    string str_json = "{\"system_list\":[{\"system_id\":\"9\",\"galaxy\":\"1\",\"x\":\"3\",\"y\":\"2\",\"system_name\":\"bla bla\"},{\"system_id\":\"10\",\"galaxy\":\"1\",\"x\":\"1\",\"y\":\"4\",\"system_name\":\"NoIQ\"}]}";
    JSONNode N;
    JSONArray arr;

    List<SystemPlanet> sysPlanet = new List<SystemPlanet>();
    void Start()
    {
        N = JSON.Parse(str_json);
        arr = N["system_list"].AsArray;

        Debug.Log(arr[0]["system_id"].AsInt);
        Debug.Log(arr[1]["system_id"].AsInt);

        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Count; i++)
        {
            sysPlanet.Add(new SystemPlanet(arr[i]["system_id"].AsInt, arr[i]["galaxy"].AsInt, arr[i]["x"].AsInt,
                arr[i]["y"].AsInt, arr[i]["system_name"].Value));
        }

        Debug.Log(sysPlanet[1].sys_name);
    }
}

public class SystemPlanet
{
    public int sys_id;
    public int galaxy;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public string sys_name;

    public SystemPlanet(int _sys_id,int _galaxy, int _x, int _y, string _sys_name)
    {
        sys_id = _sys_id;
        galaxy = _galaxy;
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        sys_name = _sys_name;
    }
}
```

If i Use This `Debug.Log(arr[0]["system_id"].AsInt);` 

or this `Debug.Log(arr[1]["system_id"].AsInt);`

**work fine**.

But if i use cycle - this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Count; i++)
{
sysPlanet.Add(new SystemPlanet(arr[i]["system_id"].AsInt, arr[i]["galaxy"].AsInt, arr[i]["x"].AsInt, arr[i]["y"].AsInt, arr[i]["system_name"].Value));
}
```

or this cycle:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Count; i++)
{
 Debug.Log("System ID: "+arr[i]["system_id"].AsInt +"\nGalaxy:"+ arr[i]["galaxy"].AsInt+"\n X: " + arr[i]["x"].AsInt +"\n Y: "+ arr[i]["y"].AsInt +"\nSystem Name: "+ arr[i]["system_name"].Value);
}
```

My Unity Editor is freeze!!! Why ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured:

I used:

`for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Count; i++)`

 when `arr.Count == 2` 
Need use this: `for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)` 

 replace `<=` to `<`
Work fine.